# Mockito unit testing: Can't test REST ressource - RESTEASY003135: Class must be annotated with @Path to invoke path(Class)

Tags: rest, mockito

I'm trying to test a REST resource with Mockito. Here is the code:

```
  @Mock
  private Service service;
  @InjectMocks
  private Resource resource;
  ....
  doNothing().when(service).createItem(anyLong(), any(Item.class));
  Response response = resource.createItem(item);
  ...
```

It raises the following exception:

```
[INFO] Running ...TestItems
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.447 s <<< FAILURE! - in ...TestItems
[ERROR] testCreateItem  Time elapsed: 0.373 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RESTEASY003135: Class must be annotated with @Path to invoke path(Class)
    at ...Tests.testCreateItem(TestItems.java:62)
```

The REST resource looks like this:

```
@Path("/items")
public class Resource
{
  ....
  @POST
  public Response createItem (Item item)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I understand that calling a REST endpoint requires a REST client but in unit tests with Mockito this is supposed to work 'cause I've seen several examples doing that. What am I doing wrong here ?

Many thanks in advance.

Seymour

Comment: Anyone please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. The mentioned exception was caused by the REST endpoint which reads something like:

```
@POST
public Response createItem (Item item)
{
  ...
  return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromResource(Item.class)
        .path("/items/{id}").build(id)).build();
}
```

Here the UriBuilder.fromResource() method which is called is the real one, of course. And it tests whether the class is annotated with @Path. Which raises the exception 'cause it isn't as it's a mock. Hence, mocking UriBuilder as follows:

```
@Mock
private UriBuilder resteasyUriBuilder = 
  new ResteasyUriBuilder().path("/items");
...
when(resteasyUriBuilder.path("/items/{id}"))
  .thenReturn(new ResteasyUriBuilder().path("/items/{id}"));
```

fixes the issue.

So, to resume, the idea was to modify the class under test such that to inject the UriBuilder and, in the unit test, to inject the mock UriBuilder class. Which means replacing the following code:

```
@POST
public Response createItem (Item item)
{
  ...
  return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromResource(Item.class)
   .path("/items/{id}").build(id)).build();
}
```

by the following one:

```
....
@Inject
private UriBuilder uriBuilder;
...
@POST
public Response createItem (Item item)
{
  ...
  Response.created(uriBuilder.path("/items/{id}").build(id)).build();
}
```

However, I'm not sure about this statement:

```
when(resteasyUriBuilder.path("/items/{id}"))
  .thenReturn(new ResteasyUriBuilder().path("/items/{id}"));
```

which is doing kind of identity transformation. Anyway ...